# How to numerically solve ODEs with a complex variable?

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I want to solve the following ODEs: 
`3(a'[z])^2 == 1/2 a[z]^2 (p'[z])^2 - 1 ;` 
`a[z]p''[z] + 3a'[z]p'[z] + z^2 == 0 ;` 
where z is generally a complex variable and a prime denotes differentiation with respect to z. The initial conditions are 
`a[0] == 0 ; a'[0] == i/Sqrt[3] ; p[0] == 5 ; p'[0] == 0 ;` 
However, when I use NDSolve for this problem, it returns that the endpoint of the variable z must be a real number. Should I always decompose the variable z into z = x + iy and transfer the problem to a PDE system with two real variable x and y? 
Besides, the solution to the ODEs should be a curve on the complex plane. How should I input the endpoint of z in NDSolve, before actually get any information from the numerical solution?

Comment: Check your equation,here z maybe  a variable instead of a function.  BTW,enclose your code in  ```     ```

Comment: Further, the function p needs initial conditions and the imaginary unit is written; I

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The correct initial condition should be ```p[0] == 5 ; p'[0] == 0 ;```. The initial condition ```a'[0] == Im/Sqrt[3] ``` contains the imaginary unit, but I don't know how to type Im correctly here. The code however still returns the same error.

Comment: The imaginary unit in Mathematica is just `I`.  Beyond that:  I'm not sure that Mathematica can automatically do numerical integration of ODEs over the complex plane.  You may have to parametrize a curve connecting the endpoints to turn it into an ODE system over a real independent variable.

Comment: I would first for starters just let z(t)=r e^{it}.  Now, convert all the derivatives with respect to z to derivatives with respect to t.  Then use NDSolve for (t,0,Pi/2) and then extract the numerical solutions, then confirm they satisfy the equations.  Get that perfected, then work up to what you want.  Rather, I would first start with just a single first-order ode in terms of complex z, get that one working in terms of t, then work up to two first-order odes, then your problem.  Can you numerically solve a very simple complex ODE say f(z)=z^2 in terms of t?